# PyCrypto 2.6 Installation Issue

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto, failed-installation

I downloaded the tar.gz file and extracted the folder, navigated to the directory in which it was stored, and typed in command prompt

```
python setup.py install
```

Which was supposed to install it, obviously. However, when I did this, I got back

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP or MPIR library not fou

building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winran
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

If possible, how can I fix this. I'm running Windows 8 (64 bit), I have Python 3.3, and I downloaded PyCrypto 2.6.

Also, someone said to download the prepackaged binary. I should have mentioned that I've tried that already. When I import it, the shell gives me another error.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Right, so I found the cryptography module that was created by those who created Python, so I've decided to use that instead.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `pip` to install it?

Comment: @shuttle87 Could you tell me how I might do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are binary packages here [Prebuilt Python Binaries for Windows](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)

If you are using `python 3.4` pip is already installed.

If you don't:

To install `pip` download this file [pypi](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py)

After you download it, run it with `python get-pip.py`.

Add `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Pythonx\Scripts"` where x is your python version or `cd` to `C:\Pythonx\Scripts`
and  run `pip install pycrypto`

After installing `Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express`.

set:

```
LIBPATH = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\LIB;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;%LIBPATH%
PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Common7\Tools;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\VCPackages;%WindowsSdkDir%bin;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33;%PATH%
INCLUDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\INCLUDE;%WindowsSdkDir%include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;C:\Python33\include;%INCLUDE%
LIB = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\LIB;%WindowsSdkDir%lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;C:\Python33\Lib;%LIB%
```

And `pip install pycrypto` again.

Comment: do you have spaces in the path to the executable or have  folders with the same name in your path? It is a common issue look here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812486

Comment: I've installed it, and when I try and use it to install pycrypto, it still says pip isn't recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: what python version are you using and what does `echo %PATH% ` return?

Comment: Thank you, I now know how to use pip. However, even using pip to download PyCrypto still brings this error: warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: I think you need Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express to compile the library code for python 3.3 and 3.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54160/discussion-between-user3236485-and-padraic-cunningham).